# Is there a way to programmatically check if a Excel file is opened

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I want to check whether a particular Excel file is already opened. Otherwise when I reopen same file in my C# program it is opening in read only format. Is there any way to find out if the file is already open?

Comment: If you want to open the file for reading purposes only, make a copy of the file prior to opening it, that will solve the "read only" problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)

Comment: @shai No,i wanted to close tht file if it is already open then,need to create new sheet and write data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file if opened by another program this code can help you figure it out, but you won't be able to open it

```
<!-- language: c# -->
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
FileStream stream = null;

    try
    {
        stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        //the file is unavailable because it is:
        //still being written to
        //or being processed by another thread
        //or does not exist (has already been processed)
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
    }

    //file is not locked
    return false;
}
```

(BUt you can't do anything with it, the file must be closed from the program, which opened it)

Comment: Why just copy the code without pointing to the [original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/937558/362938)?